# How can I use image with a 100% width and a fixed height - and have them not distort?

Tags: html, css, image, width

Google wasn't giving me anything helpful :(


I'm after a way of having an image have a 100% width, and a fixed height, say, 400px, and not stretch horribly, and instead of stretching, zoom in?


I think I'm after something not dissimilar to what backstretch does, but not for full screen backgrounds.

I think this video kind of shows what I'm after in a few instances (I think the eagle picture shows what I'm looking for) http://www.teehanlax.com/resources/img/story/medium/prototypes/feature-header.mp4


100% width picture, that's a fixed height, that shows a cropped image, and that scales with the browser.



http://jsfiddle.net/XcYfS/2/

```
<style>
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px; }

    h1, p {
        width: 80%;
        padding-left: 10%; }
</style>

<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">

<h1>Interesting Title!</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat magnam culpa obcaecati numquam iusto recusandae totam voluptatibus temporibus ipsum quasi. Nesciunt maiores sequi quis consectetur labore asperiores eaque hic ipsa!</p>
```

Comment: Cropping is the only way that I can think of, sizing the height in any way will cause distortion while maintaining 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid Distortion i think its best to use jQuery for this.

You can use **[jQuery Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)** plugin for this. It's one of the famous plugins mostly used on sites with grounds covering 100% of the width.

Here's the link for the site - http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Comment: you can make this happen without jquery or javascript. see my answer.

Comment: please refresh your browser.

Comment: This seems kinda similar to to backstretch, but I'll check it out to see that it can do what I'm after, not 100% sure it can. 
Seems really heavy for the tiny bit that I want, but thanks nonetheless :)

Comment: @Ollie It's a neat and clean plugin which is very popular among lot of developers. Here is another [DEMO]. Give it a try :).(http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/core/3.2/core.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. [Click Here for Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/XcYfS/4/)

I have edited your sample code

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" />
</div>
<h1>Interesting Title!</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat magnam culpa obcaecati numquam iusto recusandae totam voluptatibus temporibus ipsum quasi. Nesciunt maiores sequi quis consectetur labore asperiores eaque hic ipsa!</p>
```

CSS:

```
div.wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

h1, p {
    width: 80%;
    padding-left: 10%; 
}
```

The parent element of your image should be `display:inline-block;` and the width will be the width of your `img`.

if you want to position the image, lets say you want to show the center of the image, just add a negative `margin-top` to the img. [Click Here for Preview](http://www.jsfiddle.net/XcYfS/5)

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

Comment: mate, your jsfiddle links to the same URL as @Ollie's, use the `Update` button to update the jsfiddle you edited and share the link using `Share` button.

Comment: That's not working for me I'm afraid http://i.imgur.com/pU4ykA1.png :( besides I'm 99% sure it's going to require some JavaScript to do the cropping

Comment: Well i added some tweaks in CSS if this is what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/XcYfS/4/

Comment: if you want to position the image, lets say you want to show the center of the image, just add margin to the `img`. http://jsfiddle.net/XcYfS/5/